# Push Notifications not working for live tiles created programmatically

Tags: windows-phone-7, push-notification, live-tile, mpns

I have a push notification service which will update the live tile periodically. It works fine when I add a live tile to start menu using 'pin to start' option. But when I created a live tile in the App itself, the tile gets added to the start menu but it does not gets updated b push notification. Is it possible to update a live tile created in App using push notification?
Is there any other way to update a live tile programmatically?

Is it possible to increase the font size of the count in live tile and update that live tile using push notifications?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you could update `Secondary tiles` with `Push Notifications`. To identify specific tile you should pass `Url` with xml payload

```
<wp:Notification xmlns:wp="WPNotification">
     <wp:Tile ID="/MainPage.xaml?someParam=someID">
```

More info: [Push Notification Payloads](http://samidipbasu.com/2011/06/14/push-notification-payloads/)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would lik to know is it possible to update a customized live tile? I have created a live tile following the website http://vdcruijsen.net/2011/12/creating-dynamic-windows-phone-7-live-tile-images-client-side/#comment-1509. Is it possibe to update that tile also using push notifications?

Comment: Yes, you can. Also, you can update only specific data, e.g. `Back Title`, for example

Comment: Thanks for the update. I have one more doubt.<wp:Tile ID="/MainPage.xaml?someParam=someID">
what should be the values someParam=someID. can you please explain me?

Comment: I think the author of the answer meant to use someParam=someID when you create tiles in a way such that someID is unique for each tile you create. In this way when the tiles are tapped, the NavigationContext.QueryString contains a key called someParam (you might want to call it "TileID") with a unique name ("SpecialTile1" or "AlarmTile"). I'm not sure if it's called payload though: it's just a query string.

Comment: I meant Push Notification xml payload, i.e. data that sends to the MPNS. `someParam=someID` it's data that you can pass with notification, i.e. some sort of deep link

Comment: Do you need to escape the characters in the URL? e.g. > becomes &gt; etc?